# Django how to pass two different query in same view for export csv file from two different html page?

Tags: python, django

I am using this query `patient = Patient.objects.all()` for exporting all objects in csv file and this query `Patient.objects.filter(slug=slug)` for exporting single objects in csv. The main problem it's downloading single objects and all objects together in a csv file. I want single object query only run when I will be on details page and all objects query will be run when I will be on list page. here is my code:

here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
      patient_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
      patient_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
      date_of_birth = models.DateField()
      age = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
      phone =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
      email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
      slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True,blank=True,null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
    def exportcsv(request): #I am exporting csv file from this view
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv') 
        response ['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=PatientData'+str(datetime.datetime.now())+'.csv'
    
        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['patient_name'])
        
        all_patient_objects = Patient.objects.all() #exporting all objects
        single_patients_objects = Patient.objects.filter(slug=slug) #exporting single objects 

        for i in single_patients_objects: #want to run this loop only in details page
            print(i.patient_name)
            writer.writerow([i.patient_name])

        for i in all_patient_objects: #want to run this loop only in list page
            print(i.patient_name)
            writer.writerow([i.patient_name])

        return response
```

**#urls.py**

```
path('all-patient/',views.AllPatient,name='all-patient'), #list page
path('<slug:slug>/patient-details/',PatientDetails.as_view(),name='patient-details'),  #details page
path('<slug:slug>/export-csv-patient-data/',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-patient-data'),
```

Now it's downloading all objects and single objects together in a single csv file. I want it will download only single objects from details page and all objects from list page.

I want to run this loop only in **details page** for **exporting single object**:

```
for i in single_patients_objects: #want to run this loop only in details page
            print(i.patient_name)
            writer.writerow([i.patient_name])
```

I want to run this loop only in **list page** for **download all objects**:

```
 for i in all_patient_objects: #want to run this loop only in list page
            print(i.patient_name)
            writer.writerow([i.patient_name])
```

Basically I have two for loop and want to run only one for loop at a time depend on page .

Comment: Do you want to create a separate csv for each object ?

Comment: @Ahtisham I updated my questing. I want to download two different csv. When I will be on details page then it will download single object from details page and when on list page then I will download all objects from list page. Basically I have two for loop and want to run only one for loop at a time depend on page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I find one of the simplest solution. I just add another non slug url parameter in my urls.py. here is my code:

```
patient = Patient.objects.filter(slug=slug) #this query for slug url 
all_patient = Patient.objects.all() #this query for non slug url 
    
for i in patient: #this for loop will run for slug url
                   writer.writerow([i.patient_id,i.patient_name,i.date_of_birth,i.age,i.phone,i.email,i.gender,i.country,i.state,i.city,i.zip_code,i.address])

if slug == None: #this for loop only running for non slug url
            for i in all_patient:
                writer.writerow([i.patient_id,i.patient_name,i.date_of_birth,i.age,i.phone,i.email,i.gender,i.country,i.state,i.city,i.zip_code,i.address])
```

**uls.py**
now just added another non slug url.

```
 path('export-csv-patient-data/<slug:slug>/',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-patient-data'),
 path('export-csv-all-data/',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-all-data'),
```

Comment: I think that is what my solution does. You just copy pasted the solution.

Comment: Ahtisham definitely not. I tried your solution and getting errors which I commented. Yes it might be similar but exactly not same your solution. Here I am using two different url parameter and just added `if slug == None` in my original code. see my original question. I just added `slug == None` and added an an non slug url in my urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify from which page you are coming from when calling this view. One approach could be to parse query_params when calling this view. E.g.:

The export link in your details page:

```
/patient_name/export-csv-patient-data/?details=True
```

and in your exportcsv view:

```
def exportcsv(request):
    details = request.query_params.get('details')

    ...

    if details:
        # Do the stuff for the details export
    else:
        # Do the stuff for the all patients export
```

The code snippet above works for requests. in th django.restframework. For WSGIRequests:

```
def exportcsv(request):
    details = request.GET.get('details')
    
    ...
    
    if details:
        # Do the stuff for the details export
    else:
            # Do the stuff for the all patients export
```

Comment: getting this error  `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'`after using `request.query_params.get('details')`

Comment: @boyenec: You're right, my mistake. I edited my answer

Comment: @boyenec I think for this you need ajax call

Comment: can you show me an example how to call ajax?

Answer (score 1):

You can add another path for downloading all patient data like this:

***urls.py***

```
path('export-csv-patient-data/',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-patient-data'),
path('export-csv-patient-data/<slug:patient_slug>/',views.exportcsv,name='export-csv-patient-data')
# I have moved slug parameter to end instead of start as that is the convention and have also gave it a meaningful name
```

***views.py***

```
def exportcsv(request, patient_slug=None):
   # rest of the code
   params = {'slug': patient_slug} if patient_slug else {}
   patient_names = Patient.objects.filter(**params).values('patient_name')

   for patient_name in patient_names:
       writer.writerow([patient_name['patient_name']])

   return Response
```

Comment: I know it. please read my question title where I clearly said  two different query in same view

Comment: I am using two different query on the same view. You can call `/export-csv-patient-data/` for listing page and `/export-csv-patient-data/your-slug/` for details page as simple as that.

Comment: I updated the answer to use single query for both the cases. In case of no slug the query acts like `all()` otherwise gets single object based on slug.

Comment: @boyenec If it fixed your issue you can mark it as accepted

Comment: I am working on your code.

Comment: getting this error `'flat' is not valid when values_list is called with more than one field.` I have multiple fields for patient models

Comment: update the answer check now

Comment: now getting this error `'dict' object has no attribute 'patient_name'`

Comment: what value you get for `patient_name` variable in loop can you print it